# Revert staged changes, keep unstaged changes

Tags: git, commit, revert, git-reset

I have some staged and some unstaged changes in git, as well as some untracked files. I would like to keep the unstaged changes and untracked files, and discard the staged changes.

Whats the easiest way to do this on the command line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I have some staged and some unstaged changes in git, as well as some untracked files. I would like to keep the uncommited changes and untracked files, and discard the commited changes.

As you clarified in your comment, you mean "... and discard the *staged* changes" (not the *committed* changes). Normally, you would use `git reset` to undo the `git add`. But in your case you want to keep your unstaged changes, so:

```
git commit     # move staged to a commit, does not touch unstaged changes/unadded files

git checkout HEAD^    # checkout the previously committed version while keeping unstaged changes/unadded files   

git branch yourbranchname --force    # to grab the branch and move it back as well
```

Comment: Actually, the question does make sense in my use case. So I don't want to unstage, but really unstage and discard the staged changes, without losing the (currently) unstaged changes...

Comment: Yes, but you wrote "discard the committed changes". You mean "the staged changes". Important difference here, you might want to update your question.

Comment: Oh, there you're right of course, that was a typo. Thanks for the hint, I updated the question!

Answer (score 1):

```
git reset HEAD^
```

Reset HEAD to its parent, and now the commit changes are discarded in the index but kept in the work tree.

```
git checkout -- paths_of_files_whose_changes_are_to_be_discarded_in_the_work_tree
```

Discard the changes in the work tree.

Comment: Sorry there was an error in the question so I updated it (I wrote "commited" instead of "staged" mistakenly). So I think your answer doesn't fit anymore...

Comment: @JanRüegg Then, `git reset -- path_of_file` can discard the changes of the file in the index. A further `git checkout -- path_of_file` can discard the chages in the work tree.

Comment: Nice idea... however, there are quite a lot of files in the index, so I went for the other solution to save some typing ;)

Comment: @JanRüegg it's okay as long as it could help.

Answer (score 0):

To **revert unstaged changes** and **keep staged changes**, add this to your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    revert-unstaged = "!sh -c '{ git commit -m=tmp && git reset --hard HEAD && git reset --soft HEAD^ || git reset --hard HEAD; } > /dev/null 2>&1; git status'"
```

Then you can do `git revert-unstaged`, which does the following:

- Create a local commit if there are staged changes
- Delete any unstaged changes using `git reset --hard HEAD`
- If changes were staged, revert the local commit to restore them
- Run `git status` for an overview of the new state